# Using Rails to Encode Text to UTF-16LE for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, utf-16le

I have a PLC application that requires the Unicode format of UTF-16LE to support accented characters. I build the text and convert it with:

`str = Iconv.conv("utf-16le", "utf-8", str)`

Then I output the file with the following:

`send_data str, :filename => "sp_table.txt", :type => 'text/plain; charset=utf-16le; header=present;', :disposition => 'attachment'`

The PLC application is not able to display the characters. If I read the file type properties with `file -I`, I get the following:

`sp_table.txt: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

If I open the file in Notepad in Windows, it displays correctly. If I resave the file through Notepad, selecting Unicode as the encoding, `file -I` returns:

`sp_table.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-16le`

Also, after saving through Notepad, I am able to correctly display all characters in the PLC application.

Should I be specifying a different charset when I send the file?

Comment: Unless you're still on Ruby 1.8, you should be using builtin encoding services, not Iconv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad adds a BOM, whereas UTF-16LE doesn't. I am bit iffy on the ruby syntax, but something like this:

```
str = Iconv.conv("utf-16le", "utf-8", "\ufeff" + str)
```

Or

```
str = "\xFF\xFE" + Iconv.conv("utf-16le", "utf-8", str)
```

Or

```
str = "\377\376" + Iconv.conv("utf-16le", "utf-8", str)
```

Basically the idea is to add the bytes `0xFF 0xFE` (BOM for Little Endian UTF-16) at the beginning before sending them.